# Strapi endpoints shows 404 (Not Found)

Tags: reactjs, http-status-code-404, strapi

When I use this endpoint, it shows a 404 not found error in Postman.

[image: Screenshot of Postman. Transcribed below]

```
localhost:1337/api/categories
```

```json
{
    "data": null,
    "error": {
        "status": 403,
        "name": "ForbiddenError",
        "message": "Forbidden",
        "details": {}
    }
}
```

I gave access to the public and authenticated, but it's not working.

[image: Role Details: Name: Authenticated; Description: Default role given to authenticated user. Permissions: create, delete, find, findOne, update]

What should I do now to get the API data?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551), images are hard to read and troubleshoot. Please [edit] your post and add the code here as text. Be sure to take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Your question states it shows a 404 not found, but your images and code show it returns a 403 forbidden.